# Get hardware information (e.g lscpu) of an Amazon Rds Instance from the CLI

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds, hardware-infrastructure

How do I connect to the underlying instance of an AWS RDS database instance(e.g db.m5d.xlarge) to get the hardware information? I am interested in knowing the hardware information of the instance type used to launch the database.

What I intend to achieve, is to log into the instance, just as we would normally ssh into a regular ec2 instance (e.g t2.micro) and run the lscpu command to get the hardware information, but instead I want to do this with an RDS database instance such as db.m5d.xlarge.

Is this possible? If yes, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I connect to the underlying instance of an AWS RDS database instance

You don't. The whole point of a managed database service is that someone else manages the underlying hardware for you. You cannot `ssh` into an RDS instance, or run Unix commands like `lscpu` on that instance.